# Firefox non-focused tab loading priority?

Tags: firefox, tabs

I have combed google for this, and come up blank.

Firefox has a feature where the tab you have focused will load much faster than non focused tabs. Now, I find this an absolute hell, and I was wondering what I can do about this.

Is there a configuration option or something that I can mess with to stop firefox from dropping the priority on non focused tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try browsing to `about:config` and changing `browser.tabs.loadInBackground` to `false`.